Full Disk Encryption With Custom Storage Layout During Ubuntu 24.04 Installation?
During installation of fresh Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, when i select custom storage layout i can not see any option to encrypt the full disk and we are told full disk encryption is available during fresh installation, so where is the option to encrypt the full disk???


In the "Installation type" window you have the option to choose "Erase disk and install ubuntu", this option has the "Advance features", there you can choose to encrypt the new ubuntu installation. The disk layout is determinated by the installation.
By the way, I tried to install ubuntu 24.04 LTS with encryption and so far I the operating system couldn't start (when installing with disk encryption). Not sure if you need to have a custom storage layout how you could enable full disk encryption.

i need custom layout because i want things setup a certain way so why i can not encrypt disk this way? so disappointed
